# How to remove admin functionality in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm using liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5 in which some functionality like assigning a site to a new user or giving to use social office etc. So we can see here admin is assigning a site so what I want that it should be done automatically or any code so that it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it to everybody (e.g. every new user should be member of a specific site or have the same role, like "Social Office User"): Go to "ControlPanel / Configuration / Portal Settings / Users / Default User Associations" and configure as you like.

If this is not what you're asking for, please rephrase your question to be more specific.

For programmatically achieving this, you'll find a bunch of sample code in [James Falkner's blog article](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/part-ii-7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-) on the ancient sevencogs code.

Comment: i just want to assign site to a user programmatically.

Comment: Did you try to ask google for "liferay assign site to a user programmatically"? There's an API for this and the question has been asked and answered numerous times

Comment: can u please tell me the name of the API?

Comment: Liferay Hooks can help change core Liferay features: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/hooks